# A 1D numerical integral Mathematica cannot compute, from physics

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics, physics

A well know result in theoretical physics is that a sum over Matsubara fermionic frequencies, i.e.:

$$ S = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} h(\omega_n) \hspace{32pt} \omega_n=(2n+1)\frac{\pi}{\beta} $$

can be rewritten as a contour integral as

$$ S = \frac{-1}{2 \pi \mathrm{i}} \oint_C \mathrm{d} z g(z) h(-\mathrm{i}z) \hspace{32pt} g(z)=\frac{\beta}{2} \tanh(\frac{\beta z}{2})$$

where $C$ is an infinite contour enclosing counterclockwise the imaginary axis in the complex plane. This result is demonstrated, for instance, in Altand & Simons, *"Condensed Matter Field Theory"*, Cambridge University Press (2010).

If the integrand decays fast enough the contour $C$ can be split in two contours, parallel to the imaginary axis. Enough with the physics! To make a long story short the theory implies that the following functions in Mathematica should give the same result (for any choice of dist):

```
h[omega_] := omega^2/(omega^4 + omega^3 + 1)
omega[n_] := (2*n + 1)*\[Pi]/b
s1[bval_] := Sum[h[omega[n]], {n, -Infinity, Infinity}] /. {b -> bval}
g[z_, b_] := b/2 Tanh[z b/2]
s2[b_, dist_] := 1/(2*\[Pi])*NIntegrate[(g[z1, b]*h[-I*z1] - g[z2, b]*h[-I*z2])
    /. {z1 -> I*x + dist, z2 -> I*x - dist}, {x, -Infinity, Infinity},
    Method -> "DoubleExponentialOscillatory", MaxRecursion -> 16]
```

i.e. s1[b] should evaluate to the same result as s2[b,d] for any choice of b and d. However, while the sum in s1 is evaluated instantly, the integral in s2 fails to converge, even if a plot of the integrand looks good enough:

[image: Integrand of s1]

**Note:** The peaks are in infinite number, periodically spaced, but their height is rapidly decreasing. Probably this confuses Mathematica integration strategies.

I tried to change the integration method, AccuracyGoal and Precision goal, as long as increasing MaxRecursion. Sometimes the results of the integral s2 are very near to the exact result from s1, but I always get the NIntegrate::ncvb error (and most often also NIntegrate::slwcon).

I also tried to convert the infinite integral to a finite one, using:

[image]

Leading to:

```
s3[b_, dist_] := 1/(2*\[Pi])*NIntegrate[(g[z1, b]*h[-I*z1] - g[z2, b]*h[-I*z2])
    *(1 + t^2)/(1 - t^2)^2 /. {z1 -> I*t/(1 - t^2) + dist,z2 -> I*t/(1 - t^2) - dist}, 
    {t, -1, 1}]
```

And the peaks become now an oscillating behaviour at the borders, which apparently Mathematica cannot handle:

[image: Integrand of s2]

This conversion seems to help somehow, but I never get an errorless, precise answer from Mathematica.

Comment: What's a typical value for $\beta$ like?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it, for the plots I am using $\beta=0.2$. Physically speaking it is the inverse temperature, so $\beta=0.2$ corresponds to high temperatures.

Comment: I just tried $\beta=10$ and $\beta=20$, the convergence problems are unchanged. They disappear in the low-temperature limit, $\beta=100$, for example.

Comment: Do you really need to use contour integration to evaluate your infinite sum? There are a lot of alternative approaches you could use for infinite summation...

Comment: `g` is undefined in the question.  I presume it should be `g[z_, bval_] := bval/2 Tanh[z bval/2]`

Comment: Many thanks! I modified the question to add it!

Comment: J.M. is back: care to elaborate? The usual way in physics textbook to calculate that sum is to convert it to a contour integral. I'm no expert in this field, which other options do I have to numerically calculate an infinite sum? Note that here I chose a very simple $h(\omega)$ usually it is more complicated...

Comment: I've done contour integral summation before, and its very sensitive to the choice of contour. You might want to look at a plot of your integrand in the complex plane; make sure your contours aren't passing through particularly wiggly areas.

Comment: Anyway, do you have an example of a not-too-complicated $h(\omega)$ that does not admit closed-form summation?

Comment: @zakk I cannot reproduce your first plot with {dist,b}={2,0.2}. From the plot I see for those values the integral can be zero. With the code below you will get NIntegrate to converge. Do the results meet your expectations? Clear[x];
Block[{b = 0.2, dist = 2, z1, z2, ranges},
 z1 = I*x + dist; z2 = I*x - dist;
 ranges = {{x, -\[Infinity], -1}, {x, -1, 0}, {x, 0, 1}, {x, 
    1, \[Infinity]}};
 Table[1/(2*\[Pi])*
   NIntegrate[(g[z1, b]*h[-I*z1] - g[z2, b]*h[-I*z2]), r, 
    MinRecursion -> 9, MaxRecursion -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 2], {r, 
   ranges}]]
Total[%]

Comment: Usually for what I need $h (\omega)$ is the result of a numeric integral over other variables, so does not have an analytic form. The problem is more complicated (two numeric integrations + an infinite sum to end with...). Modifying the contour choice is great advice, thanks! I'm looking into it right now...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To understand this integral, it is helpful to know the location of the poles.  The poles of `g` are given by

```
poleg = Simplify[Solve[Cosh[beta z/2] == 0, z], C[1] ∈ Integers] /. C[1] -> n;
(z /. #) & /@ poleg
(* {(I (-1 + 4 n) π)/beta, (I (π + 4 n π))/beta} *)
```

which agrees with the expression in the Question.  However, `h` also has poles.

```
poleh = Solve[Denominator[h[-I z]] == 0, z];
N[z /. #] & /@ poleh
(* {-0.66661 + 0.518913 I, -0.602565 - 1.01891 I, 0.602565 - 1.01891 I, 
    0.66661 + 0.518913 I} *)
```

The contour integral is equal to the sum of residues of all enclosed poles.  Consider now the value of the integral for `beta = 0.2` as `dist` is varied.  (Quiet is applied to eliminate a plethora of error messages that, nonetheless, do not prevent reasonable results.)

```
Quiet@Table[{dist, s2[2/10, dist] // Chop}, {dist, .5, .7, .01}];
ListPlot[%]
```

[image]

Only integrals for `dist < 0.602565` would be expected to equal `s1[0.2]`, and indeed that is the case.

```
s1[2/10] // N // Chop
(* 0.0100333 *)
```

The average value of the integral for `dist < 0.602565`, as shown in the plot, is about `0.01002`, which seems like reasonable agreement.

**Addendum**

Because the contour integrals enclosing all poles seem to be equal to zero (approximately `-10^-5` in the plot), it follows that the sum of the `g` residues must equal the negative of the sum of the `h` residues.  Symbolic expressions for the `h` residues are quite lengthy but can be greatly simplified with `N`.

```
-Simplify[Total[N[Residue[h[-I z] g[z, beta], {z, z /. #}]] & /@ poleh]]
(* -beta ((-0.0772029 + 0.0405577 I) Tan[(0.259456 + 0.333305 I) beta] - 
          (0.0772029 - 0.172992 I) Tan[(0.509456 + 0.301283 I) beta] - 
          (0.172992 - 0.0772029 I) Tanh[(0.301283 + 0.509456 I) beta] - 
          (0.0405577 - 0.0772029 I) Tanh[(0.333305 + 0.259456 I) beta]) *)
(% /. beta -> .2) // Chop
(* 0.0100333 *)
```

as expected.